# How to setup OpenID to work with load balancer?

Tags: flask, openid, keycloak, flask-oidc

The stack I'm currently using is:
Keycloak
flask
flask-oidc
nginx as load balancer

The set up I'm having is I have two instances of a service running (instance1, instance2). The issue I'm facing is:

1. A user uses web browser to authenticate by going to https://mycompany.com/auth/login
2. instance1 handles this request and redirects the user to Keycloak for authentication
3. Keycloak redirects the user back to the app using redirect url (https://mycompany.com/auth/auth_callback)
4. This time the load balancer routes the request to the redirect url to instance2. Here instance2 errors out with a response from Keycloak saying "{'error': 'invalid_grant', 'description': 'Incorrect redirect uri'}", which is very confusing because the redirect uri is correct.

   I am not entirely sure why this set up is not working. But after reading through how openID works, I kind of suspect it has to do with the state parameter (https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state). Again, I am not entirely sure. But it has to be something that's only local to instance1, which instance2 doesn't have.

How do people tackle this issue ? Is this set up even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> Note that you should probably provide the library with a place to store the credentials it has retrieved for the user. These need to be stored in a place where the user themselves or an attacker can not get to them. To provide this, give an object that has **setitem** and **getitem** dict APIs implemented as second argument to the **init**() call. Without this, the library will only work on a single thread, and only retain sessions until the server is restarted.

It is referring to `credentials_store` option in `OpenIDConnect` instantiation. To support persisted login via multiple application instances, you will need a persisted shared datastore for this use case. You could use a share redis or dynamodb instance.

Implementation of this `credentials_store` is fairly simple, you can try something like,

```
class RedisOpenIdCredStore:
    def __init__(self):
        # Handle Redis instance initialisation here
        pass

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # Set item to redis
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # Fetch and return item from redis if present
        pass

credential_store = RedisOpenIdCredStore()
oid_connect = OpenIDConnect(app, credential_store=credential_store, ...)
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I'll give this a try.